# Vectorization of array comparison

Tags: matlab, vectorization, jit

I have surjective functions created by matching one element in an array `MatchesX.trainIdx` to one or more  elements in a second array `MatchesX.queryIdx`.

To obtain only the bijective elements of said funciton I run the same function forward

```
Matches1=Matcher.match(Descriptors1,Descriptors2);
```

and then backwards

```
Matches2=Matcher.match(Descriptors2,Descriptors1);
```

and then look for the elements occuring in both function in following fashion:

```
k=1;
DoubleMatches=Matches1;

for i=1:length(Matches1)
    for j=1:length(Matches2)
        if((Matches1(i).queryIdx==Matches2(j).trainIdx)&&(Matches1(i).trainIdx==Matches2(j).queryIdx))
            DoubleMatches(k)=Matches1(i);
            k=k+1;
       end
   end
end

DoubleMatches(k:end)=[];
```

This of course does the work, but it is rather unelegant and seems to bother the JIT accelerator (calc time with `accel on` and `accel off` is the same).

Can you think of a way to vectorize this expresion? Is there any other way of avoiding the JIT from "striking"?

Thanks a lot and sorry about the strange structs, I'm working with MEX-functions. Let me know if rewriting the code in "normal" arrays would help

Comment: What kind of thing is `Matches1`? An object of a class you defined? I don't get how the syntax `Matches1(i).queryIdx` can be correct... (but I never used classes in Matlab so that might be the issue)

Comment: This is actually a quite well-posed question; I'm going to use this one as an exemplary question to refer others to, if that's all right with you?

Comment: @reverse_engineer: Hi, MatchesX are structs, that's structures with various elements (hence the Matches(i)) and various values in different fields of each element (one of them being .queryIdx).

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Hi Rody, thanks for the compliment. Please feel free to use it as an example whenever you need it! Btw: thank you for your great answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access to data in multi-dimensional structures is notoriously slow in MATLAB, so transforming your data to an ordinary array will certainly help:

```
kk = 1;
DoubleMatches = Matches1;

%// transform to regular array
Matches1queryIdx = [Matches1.queryIdx];
Matches1trainIdx = [Matches1.trainIdx];

Matches2queryIdx = [Matches2.queryIdx];
Matches2trainIdx = [Matches2.trainIdx];

%// loop through transformed data instead of structures
for ii = 1:length(Matches1queryIdx)
    for jj = 1:length(Matches1queryIdx)
        if((Matches1queryIdx(ii)==Matches2trainIdx(jj)) && ...
                (Matches1trainIdx(ii)==Matches2queryIdx(jj)))
            DoubleMatches(kk) = Matches1(ii);
            kk = kk+1;
        end
    end
end

DoubleMatches(kk:end)=[];
```

There is also a solution that is almost entirely vectorized:

```
matches = sum(...
    bsxfun(@eq, [Matches1.queryIdx], [Matches2.trainIdx].') & ...
    bsxfun(@eq, [Matches1.trainIdx], [Matches2.queryIdx].'));

contents = arrayfun(@(x)..
    repmat(Matches1(x),1,matches(x)), 1:numel(matches), ...
    'Uniformoutput', false);

DoubleMatches2 = [contents{:}]';
```

Note that this can be a lot more memory intensive (it has O(N²) peak memory footprint, as opposed to O(N) for the others, although the data type at peak memory is `logical` and thus 8x smaller than `double`...). Better do some checks beforehand which one you should use.

A little test. I used the following dummy data:

```
Matches1 = struct(...
    'queryIdx', num2cell(randi(25,1000,1)),...
    'trainIdx', num2cell(randi(25,1000,1))...
);

Matches2 = struct(...
    'queryIdx', num2cell(randi(25,1000,1)),...
    'trainIdx', num2cell(randi(25,1000,1))...
);
```

and the following test:

```
%// Your original method
tic    
    kk = 1;
    DoubleMatches = Matches1;

    for ii = 1:length(Matches1)
        for jj = 1:length(Matches2)
            if((Matches1(ii).queryIdx==Matches2(jj).trainIdx) && ...
                    (Matches1(ii).trainIdx==Matches2(jj).queryIdx))
                DoubleMatches(kk) = Matches1(ii);
                kk = kk+1;
            end
        end
    end

    DoubleMatches(kk:end)=[];

toc

DoubleMatches1 = DoubleMatches;


%// Method with data transformed into regular array
tic

    kk = 1;
    DoubleMatches = Matches1;

    Matches1queryIdx = [Matches1.queryIdx];
    Matches1trainIdx = [Matches1.trainIdx];

    Matches2queryIdx = [Matches2.queryIdx];
    Matches2trainIdx = [Matches2.trainIdx];

    for ii = 1:length(Matches1queryIdx)
        for jj = 1:length(Matches1queryIdx)
            if((Matches1queryIdx(ii)==Matches2trainIdx(jj)) && ...
                    (Matches1trainIdx(ii)==Matches2queryIdx(jj)))
                DoubleMatches(kk) = Matches1(ii);
                kk = kk+1;
            end
        end
    end

    DoubleMatches(kk:end)=[];

toc

DoubleMatches2 = DoubleMatches;


% // Vectorized method
tic

    matches = sum(...
        bsxfun(@eq, [Matches1.queryIdx], [Matches2.trainIdx].') & ...
        bsxfun(@eq, [Matches1.trainIdx], [Matches2.queryIdx].'));

    contents = arrayfun(@(x)repmat(Matches1(x),1,matches(x)), 1:numel(matches), 'Uniformoutput', false);

    DoubleMatches3 = [contents{:}]';

toc

%// Check if all are equal
isequal(DoubleMatches1,DoubleMatches2, DoubleMatches3)
```

Results:

```
Elapsed time is 6.350679 seconds. %// (  1×) original method
Elapsed time is 0.636479 seconds. %// (~10×) method with regular array
Elapsed time is 0.165935 seconds. %// (~40×) vectorized
ans =
     1                            %// indeed, outcomes are equal
```

Comment: What an amazing answer! I did not believe that accessing the structs was that slow! Glad to learn something new. The vectorization seems really fast too, I looked for it a long while but just couldn't find it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Matcher.match returns array of the same objects as passed to it as arguments you can solve this like this

```
% m1 are all d1s which have relation to d2
m1 = Matcher.match(d1,d2);
% m2 are all d2s, which have relation to m1
% and all m1 already have backward relation
m2 = Matcher.match(d2,m1);
```

Comment: hi @divanov, that would be indeed be a very logical way to solve the problem, but unfortunately the arguments this function takes are different and I have no way to construct an input out of an output. Thank you anyway!